# Xaxis set extremes in highstock options

Tags: highcharts, angular-highcharts

I'm using a highstock column type chart, and I want to set the xAxis extremes with the options.

Basically I'm looking for the options equivalent of the setExtremes method:

```
this.chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` and `max` properties or call `setExtremes` method after the chart is created.

```
xAxis: {
    ...,
    min: -10,
    max: 20
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2b9zomxh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis

Comment: This worked. The problem I had was that I used setExtremes first, then trying to set min/max to null to reset. This doesn't work, I guess because the options don't change when calling setExtremes, therefore the min/max was already null.

Comment: Removing the setExtremes completely and setting min/max whenever I need to change the xAxis did the trick for me. Thanks!